# How to use the openGL events handler ? [64 BITS]

Tags: events, opengl

I'm learning how to use the openGL but I only find tutorials using SDL functions for manage windows and events.

This the code I made with this tutorial:

```
#include <GL/gl.h>
#include <GL/glu.h>
#include <SDL/SDL.h>
#include <GL/gl.h>
#include <GL/glu.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{

  SDL_Init(SDL_INIT_VIDEO);
  SDL_WM_SetCaption("Mon premier programme OpenGL !",NULL);
  SDL_SetVideoMode(640, 480, 32, SDL_OPENGL);

  bool continuer = true;
  SDL_Event event;

  while (continuer)
    {
      SDL_WaitEvent(&event);
      switch(event.type)
    {
        case SDL_QUIT:
          continuer = false;
    }
      glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
      glBegin(GL_TRIANGLES);
      glColor3ub(255,0,0);    glVertex2d(-0.75,-0.75);
      glColor3ub(0,255,0);    glVertex2d(0,0.75);
      glColor3ub(0,0,255);    glVertex2d(0.75,-0.75);
      glEnd();
      glFlush();
      SDL_GL_SwapBuffers();
    }
  SDL_Quit();
  return 0;
```

}

I'm ok tu use the SDL functions to manage windoxs but I would use the openGL events handler.

Does someone know how to replace and how to use it ?

Thanks

Comment: "the openGL events handler"...what?  Like...[GLUT](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OpenGL_Utility_Toolkit), maybe?

Comment: One tutorial using GLUT for OpenGL user input is [these course notes](http://www.sci.sjp.ac.lk/vle/mod/resource/view.php?id=1457) :  there are plenty more online.

Answer (score 4):

OpenGL does not have an event handler. It focuses on drawing, not input.

To handle window events and input, you need to either use the OS facilities, or use a library like GLFW, GLUT, or SDL that helps/abstracts them.

Comment: Can you please tell me how to add the GLUT event handler on my previous code ?

Comment: @ballain732 there are plenty of tutorials and docs on how to use glut on the internet.

Answer (score 1):

> Does someone know how to replace and how to use it?

No. Because it doesn't exist.

OpenGL is focused on one thing: Drawing stuff to *some* framebuffer. In the case of a window framebuffer OpenGL has no capabilities in creating or managing it, and depends entirely on the operating system functions for this. SDL, GLUT, GLFW, Qt, … shrink-wrap the process of interacting with the OS in easy to use way, portable libraries with a cross-platform API.